# Implementing javascript menu into website

Tags: javascript, menu

I am following a tutorial on creating a javascript menu and have successfully got it working in a blank html file. However, I've tried to get it working in my index page and it just isn't working.

I've linked the working nav which is [nav2.html](http://www.ugcudevelopment.talktalk.net/nav2.html), the one I'm trying to get working which is [index.htm](http://www.ugcudevelopment.talktalk.net/index.htm) JS files are in a folder on the root called js and the css files are in a folder on the root called css.

I suspect that I need to edit the html code a bit so it will work in the index file but I've tried everything I can and it still isn't working.

Would appreciate your help

Calebk

Comment: Please check this these Much Resources are not Loaded correctly                FFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.ugcudevelopment.talktalk.net/scripts/jquery.1.7.1.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.ugcudevelopment.talktalk.net/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.ugcudevelopment.talktalk.net/scripts/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (

Answer (score 1):

OK several things:

1. Your header's overflow is set to hidden effectively hiding the menu so you'll have to change that, you can try setting it to overflow:visible which removes that problem but then the header overflows to the right so you'll have to fix that.
2. Remove the position:absolute from the submenu  as it's positioning it wrong.
3. Slider is also hiding the submenu, so to fix that you'll have to increase the z-index of the #topNav div to let's say z-index:10

After making those changes this is the result: http://prntscr.com/13f2lu